# Is there anything like type inference in Apex?

Tags: type-inference, apex

Working my way through [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) code modules feels like stepping back in time (having spent the last few years working in c# and JavaScript), is there anything (a tool or modern compiler/runtime) that can infer type specifically for things like for loops like this?

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Siebel']; 

for(Account a : accs){
  a.Name = 'Oracle';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the generic **SObject** class **SObjectType** class and **getDescribe()** calls.  Also looking at [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) might get you closer to what you are looking for.  But still there are alot of limitation with the language.